# How resolve Error:(4, 1) TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof moment' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript 3.* and momentjs for dates 
and I got compile time errors.

> Error:(3, 13) TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof moment' has no compatible call signatures.

so,I looked for a solution to solve this error.
 And find the following article,
I did the same thing as the solution described in the article.

but I got compile time error, again.

> Error:(1, 8) TS1192: Module '"/Users/hogehoge/Work/Work_Fork/hoge/node_modules/moment/moment"' has no default export.

Here is My tsconfig and my programs.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "newLine": "LF",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

```
import moment from 'moment';

console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have your package.json, so I reproduced your situation this way:

```
npm init
npm i typescript moment @types/node
```

File `test.ts`

```
let moment = require("moment");
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

(using `require` instead of `import`)

Then executed the "compiler":

```
_modules/.bin/tsc test.ts
```

No errors, this way it worked fine for me.
As of today, the script returns `2019-09-30`.